# How to stop a foreach() loop while reading from a textfile?

Tags: php, html

I'm making a website for my clan.
I'd like to have a dynamic table of contents on the left.

E.G. If you click on the link "games" it should stop and print the other list. A list in a list.

I know, that sounds pretty strange, I think it'd be the best if I'll show you my code.

Here it is:

```
    <div class="links">
    <?php
        $zeilen = file ('../inhaltsverzeichnis.txt');
        foreach ($zeilen as $zeile)
        {
        if($zeile == 3)
        {
            $games = file ('games_inhaltsverzeichnis.txt');
            foreach ($games as $game)
            {
                echo $game;
            }
        }
        else
        {
        echo $zeile;
        }
        }
    ?>
```

I hope you know what I mean.

Comment: You can use `break;`.

Comment: Should work as is. What's the problem?

Comment: How can I say he should stop reading the textfile when the line "games" come?

Answer (score 1):

The [break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) statement allows you to escape from the "nearest enclosing loop". If you add an argument (e.g. `break 2;`), you escape "the nearest two loops". Not absolutely sure how your code relates to the description of the problem (the title of the question), or where you would want the `break` statement - but that's what you need.

Comment: How can I say he should stop reading the textfile when the line "games" come?

Comment: If you are in the inner loop and you want to go all the way out of the two `foreach` loops, you say `if ($game == "games") break 2;` assuming that "when the line "games" come" means: "when the variable "$game" is equal to the string "games".